# How to test with Enzyme shallow and component based UIs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, enzyme, semantic-ui-react

We are using the  [Semantic React UI library](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction). The code often looks like:

```
<div className="EditTemplateMetaDataPage">
        <Page title={...}>
          <Container text>
            <Segment>
              <Grid columns={1}>
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Button ...>
```

This might be interesting for many people, using similar React Component libraries like Material UI or Bootstrap React.

We currently use `mount` with the `enzyme` library instead of `shallow`, because we would render only one level deep 
, to the first `<Grid>` component in a test, which is just a visual helper, while we really need the deeper buried `Button` instead.

Because of performance and to avoid **overlapping tests** it is recommended to use `shallow`. (We follow [London school TDD](https://github.com/testdouble/contributing-tests/wiki/London-school-TDD), and check only that sub-components exist and their interfaces are used properly)

We came up with using CSS-only for visual components, i.e.

```
<div className='ui one column grid'>
```

instead of:

```
<Grid columns={1}>
```

But we are not sure, whether this is the optimal approach. Do you have other ideas? How can we use `shallow(...)` in this case?

Comment: Would breaking up the components apart from the semantic-ui-react wrappers and testing them on their own, help?

For example if you have a card-like structure that is supposed to live inside a Semantic-UI grid, break into a separate Card component, and test it by itself?

Comment: Have been thinking about a similar solution @DimitrisKaragiannis! This is also a general best practice when working with React components. The problem is, imagine you just want to assert that The `WrapperComponent` **contains** a list of these `CardComponent`s, e.g. another wrapper called `CardComponentList`. This is not possible as long as they're in a `Grid`. As long as `Grid`, `Segment` etc. are used for basic layout structuring, these things become very hary. I think i will use native DOM elements for that. This is also a clearer separation of concerns between functional and pure design.

Answer (score 0):

shallow actually allow you to use your component as selector, so you can do something like

```
import Button from '../Button'

const page = shallow(<Page />)

expect(page.find(Button).length).toBe(1)
```

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html

Comment: The `Button` is not found when using `shallow`, because `shallow` renders only one level deep. (That's actually the purpose of shallow) On this level there is only a `<Grid/>` but no `Button`. That's because `Grid` is a component itself. (see my nested example above)

Comment: @headphones try `page.find(Grid).dive().find(Button)`

Comment: Great find @SeanWu! This would basically work. The thing is, in deeply nested structures one would need to chain `dive()`-calls, because `dive`-also shallow renders. (Which is good, otherwise we would use `mount`). But i think the overall experience is still better when using native DOM elements, as described above. And when using `dive` i'm implicitly stating that the component must have a specific nesting structure. This is not the object under test, so i would not want to have these things in my tests. Nevertheless, thank you for the hint!

Comment: @headphones That's correct. With `dive` you only test what you want and not any unneeded children